# Has anyone experienced this error installing and using air via docker?

Tags: docker, air

```
error obtaining VCS status: exit status 128
        Use -buildvcs=false to disable VCS stamping.
failed to build, error: exit status 1
running...
/bin/sh: /src/tmp/main: not found
error obtaining VCS status: exit status 128
        Use -buildvcs=false to disable VCS stamping.
```

My docker configurations

```bash
FROM golang:1.19.2-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add git make curl openssh-client

# Add a work directory
WORKDIR /src

# Install air for development
RUN curl -fLo install.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmtrek/air/master/install.sh \
    && chmod +x install.sh && sh install.sh && cp ./bin/air /bin/air

# Start app
CMD air start
```

use air to reload in my code

Comment: You can't change the contents of an image once you've built it (Docker uses _immutable images_), which means it doesn't usually make sense to use a live-reloading tool in a container.  Can you `go install` this tool in your host environment instead?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the necessary dependencies are properly installed by running **go mod vendor** and you are using stable versions of go (1.17) and alpine (3.16).

Comment: All dependencies are working, I noticed this problem is only on my machine.